# Микросервисная архитектура: http или rabbitmq

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core, rabbitmq

Имеется, например, 2 сервиса:

- `Сервис №1`, выполняющий все операции с пользователей
- `Сервис №2` по загрузки пользовательских файлов.

При регистрации пользователя (указывает какой-то набор данных) из "другой" системы приходит вся информация о нем вместе с изображением. Теперь это изображение нужно передать для загрузки в `Сервис №2`.

**ВОПРОС:**
  Что для этого использовать:  передать по http или использовать шину сообщений, например RabbitMq (целесообразно ли это? используют ли брокер сообщения для таких задач?), нужно ли так дробить?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Серебряной пули не существует. Для решения что выбрать следует смотреть не только на то что нужно сделать. А также

1. Как вы потом собираетесь это использовать
2. Как будете расширять
   функционал (как добавлять ещё сервисы)
3. Как масштабировать
4. Разнесены ли сервисы по сети
5. Будет ли картинка передаваться вместе с запросом либо только ссылка на неё (если только ссылка, то где она будет хранится как её от туда доставать)
6. Как долго она будет
   обрабатываться, нужно ли ждать ответ.
7. Нужно ли просматривать текущие задачи сервисов (какая картинка обрабатывается сейчас, какие в очереди)

Таких вопросов несколько десятков (если не сотен).

При проектировании, если вы не знаете что выбрать сейчас то лучше сделайте некоторую абстракцию над вашим транспортным уровнем. Тогда вы сможете с минимальной болью (по крайней мере, боли будет меньше, чем если вы сразу выберете какой либо вариант, который потом будет сложно поддерживать) изменить передачу c http на очередь сообщений, 0mq, apache thrift или ещё что то.